# c++ hash function for an int array

Tags: c++, hash

I need to specialize the hash function for `unordered_map` so I can use int arrays as keys.  The array values are usually 0 or 1, e.g. `int array = {0, 1, 0, 1}`, but technically not bounded.

Can someone recommend a good hash function in this case?  Alternatively, I can always convert the int array into a string and avoid specialization. But I am concerned about performance since I may have several million of these arrays.

Comment: Use or mimic Boost's "range hash". It's built up by repeatedly calling `hash_combine`, which is also in Boost and should really be in the standard.

Comment: If you do have several million of those arrays, I suggest new algorithms/data structures...

Comment: @Blindy What data structures would you suggest?

Comment: @Kerreck,http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/hash_range_id420926.html says it is not appropriate for unordered containers. Does this not apply in my case?

Comment: @gewizz: that is sloppy wording. It is not appropriate to get a deterministic hash of an unordered container _as a whole_ [the ordering could depend on the load factor and number of reallocations done]. However, **of course** it is appropriate to use as the **element hash function** to an unordered container

Comment: Isn't keyType required to be assignable? Arrays usually are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ TR1 contains a hash template function.

If you don't have that yet, you can use Boost Hash.

Idea for a handy helper:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

template <typename T, int N>
    static std::size_t hasharray(const T (&arr)[N])
{
     return boost::hash_range(arr, arr+N);
}
```

This would be (roughly?) equivalent to

```
 size_t seed = 0;
 for (const T* it=arr; it!=(arr+N); ++it)
     boost::hash_combine(seed, *it);
 return seed;
```

**Don't forget to implement proper equality comparison operations if you're using this hash for lookup**

Comment: I think it should be `std::size_t N` because `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be able to represent the size of the largest possible array, while `int` might overflow (depending on the system).  Plus, it doesn't need to be a signed type.

Comment: @outofthecave fair points. However, unsigned is contagious and that makes it unwieldy for offsets (they can be negative, and `N - 10` will just wrap around if `N<10`. Surprise!). Also, arrays statically typed at larger than 2³¹ elements? Those are rare. And you'd not often be hashing them, if you had them.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use [lookup8](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup8.c) hash function. This function is VERY fast and good.

```
int key[100];
int key_size=10;
for (int i=0;i<key_size;i++) key[i]=i; //fill key with sample data
ub8 hash=hash((ub8*)key, sizeof(key[0])*key_size, 0);
```

UPD: Or use better function. - [t1ha](https://github.com/erthink/t1ha)

Comment: Usually hash functions are written in plain c. You can create C++ wrapper for it.

Comment: Usually, hash functions are written *in the language at hand*.

Comment: You always write function like crc32, sha, md5 or use existing well tested and hi-performance implementations? :)

Comment: The function is too complex to be used at compile time